# Error running Wordpress locally on the Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the [Quick Start WordPress for Google App Engine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) guide on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm at the step where I have to run `dev_appserver.py`, such as in the given example

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=~/php-5.4.25/installdir/bin/php-cgi path_to_this_directory
```

I've cloned the Github repository into the directory `/Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project`, and from there I tried to run this command as follows:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:/Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project$ dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi /Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project
INFO     2016-09-20 20:57:51,681 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-09-20 20:57:51,756 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:45719
INFO     2016-09-20 20:57:51,765 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-09-20 20:57:51,766 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

I'm not getting any error messages; however, if I visit `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php` in my browser I get a "404 Not Found":

[image]

What could have gone wrong?

**Update**
If I check `localhost:8080`, I do get the following error messages:

```
Warning: require(/Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/wordpress/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 147

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/wordpress/index.php' (include_path='.:/Kurt/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project:/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/php/sdk') in /home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php on line 147
```

Comment: Are you meaning to run this from inside your Downloads directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, you visited port 8000.  `8000` is the admin port.  You want `8080` for the default module.  So: `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php`.